# Fetched data needs to have One To Many relationship with existing entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, backend

I am building an backend service for an app. I have an entity defined, we can call it E1. This entity is related to another entity, which we can call E2, by Many to One relationship. The only problem is, there is an existing API that returns a list of all E2, and I was wondering how I could use the fact that there is already an existing api for E2 to my advantage, and what is in general the best way to engineer a service in this use case. So far I have come up with a couple of solutions:

1. Fetch the data for E2 with the existing API, save it to a table in a database and connect it with E1 with a foreign key somehow.
   1.1. Create a job with Spring Batch to fetch the data every few couple of hours to refresh the list of E2.
2. Call the existing API from the front-end and store only the used data to a table in the backend. This way I would always have the latest E2 list, but I am not sure whether this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have it mapped between E1 and E2.

with E1 has a list of E2 it should have stored on the DB table the id of E2 for each association.

you can create a query to get all values that you need.
when you are saving a new object E2 you need to pass the E1 object or the id to save it with the correct association.

for the current scenario, I don't see it necessary to create a job to update the list